# Restringir movimiento del puntero del ratón

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

Estaba retomando viejos proyectos personales y profundizando en el uso del Graphics View Framework y tengo el siguiente código, que básicamente crea objetos derivados de `QGraphicsItem` en el que se ha implementado la función `QVariant itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value);` para que al moverlos presionando el botón izquierdo del ratón, este movimiento se restrinja a la rejilla.

Ahora lo que me gustaría es que el propio puntero del ratón también se restringiera a la rejilla, de forma que fuera "saltando" entre cada punto. He intentado implementar un filtro de eventos, pero parece que no reacciona al movimiento del ratón.

Esto es lo que tengo:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include "scene.h"
#include "customrectitem.h"

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);
private:
    QGraphicsView* view;
    QGraphicsScene* scene;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMouseEvent>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    scene = new Scene(this);
    scene->setSceneRect(10,10,400,400);
    view = new QGraphicsView(scene);
    setCentralWidget(view);

    CustomRectItem* rectItem1 = new CustomRectItem(QRect(0,0,100,100));
    rectItem1->setPos(50,50);
    rectItem1->setBrush(Qt::gray);
    scene->addItem(rectItem1);

    CustomRectItem* rectItem2 = new CustomRectItem(QRect(0,0,60,60));
    rectItem2->setPos(160,60);
    rectItem2->setBrush(Qt::magenta);
    scene->addItem(rectItem2);

    setMouseTracking(true);
    installEventFilter(this);
}

bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (obj == this)
    {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove)
        {
            qDebug()<<"evento";
            QMouseEvent *mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
            qDebug()<<mouseEvent->pos().x()<<mouseEvent->pos().y();
        }
    }
    return QMainWindow::eventFilter(obj,event);
}
```

**scene.h**

```
#ifndef SCENE_H
#define SCENE_H

#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QApplication>

class Scene : public QGraphicsScene
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Scene(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    int getGridSize() const {return this->gridSize;}

protected:
    void drawBackground (QPainter* painter, const QRectF &rect);
private:
    int gridSize;
};

#endif // SCENE_H
```

**scene.cpp**

```
#include "scene.h"

Scene::Scene(QObject *parent) : QGraphicsScene(parent), gridSize(20)
{
    Q_ASSERT(gridSize > 0);
}

void Scene::drawBackground(QPainter *painter, const QRectF &rect)
{
    QPen pen(Qt::black);
    QBrush brocha(Qt::white);
    painter->setPen(pen);
    painter->setBrush(brocha);
    painter->fillRect(rect,brocha);

    qreal left = int(rect.left()) - (int(rect.left()) % gridSize);
    qreal top = int(rect.top()) - (int(rect.top()) % gridSize);
    QVector<QPointF> points;
    for (qreal x = left; x < rect.right(); x += gridSize){
        for (qreal y = top; y < rect.bottom(); y += gridSize){
            points.append(QPointF(x,y));
        }
    }
    painter->drawPoints(points.data(), points.size());
}
```

**customrectitem.h**

```
#ifndef CUSTOMRECTITEM_H
#define CUSTOMRECTITEM_H

#include <QGraphicsRectItem>
#include "scene.h"    

class CustomRectItem : public QGraphicsRectItem
{
public:
    CustomRectItem(const QRect& rect, QGraphicsItem* parent = nullptr);
protected:
    QVariant itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change,
                        const QVariant &value);
};

#endif // CUSTOMRECTITEM_H
```

**customrectitem.cpp**

```
#include "customrectitem.h"
#include <cmath>

CustomRectItem::CustomRectItem(const QRect& rect, QGraphicsItem* parent):
    QGraphicsRectItem(rect, parent)
{
    setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable |
            QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable |
            QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsGeometryChanges);
}

QVariant CustomRectItem::itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value)
{
    if (change == ItemPositionChange && scene())
    {
        QPointF newPos = value.toPointF();
        if(QApplication::mouseButtons() == Qt::LeftButton && qobject_cast<Scene*> (scene()))
        {
            Scene* customScene = qobject_cast<Scene*> (scene());
            int gridSize = customScene->getGridSize();
            qreal xV = newPos.x();
            qreal yV = newPos.y();
            qreal rX = round(newPos.x()/gridSize)*gridSize;
            qreal rY = round(newPos.y()/gridSize)*gridSize;
            if (fabs(xV-rX)<(gridSize/2) && fabs(yV-rY)<(gridSize/2))
            {
                return QPointF(rX, rY);
            }
            else
            {
                return newPos;
            }
        }
        else
            return newPos;
    }
    else
        return QGraphicsItem::itemChange(change, value);
}
```